# JPA Query on sublclass with SingleTable inheritance

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, criteria-api, java-ee-7

Say I have the following entities:

```java
@Entity
public class Container
{
    @OneToMany
    Set<AbstractElement> elements;

    //getter setter and other attributes...
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "CLASS_CODE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 10)
public abstract class AbstractElement<T> extends AbstractEntity
{
    @Transient
    T value;

    //getter setter and other attributes...
}

@DiscriminatorValue(value = "BOOL")
@Entity
public class BooleanElement extends AbstractElement<Boolean>
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Column(name = "VALUE_BOOL")
    @Override
    public Boolean getValue()
    {
        return super.getValue();
    }
}
```

The question is this:

How can I execute a jpa criteria query on the value of the BooleanElement, starting from the class CONTAINER?

What I actually have so far is this:

```java
CriteriaQuery<Container> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Container.class);
Root<Container> from = criteriaQuery.from(Container.class);
criteriaQuery.select(from);
from = from.join("elements");
Predicate pred = criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.treat(from ,BooleanElement.class).get("value"), FOO);

//etc......
```

The exception at this point is that "there is not VALUE attributes on the AbstractEntity".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Treat operator doesn't work in this specific case.
The as operator on the joins it's still not so clear how to implement: i get class cast exception at line 3 when doing this:

```
CriteriaQuery<AbstractElement> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(AbstractElement.class);
Root<AbstractElement> rootAbstract = criteriaQuery.from(AbstractElement.class);
Path predPath = (Path)rootAbstract.as(BooleanElement.class);
predPath.get("value");
```

The only way to execute this type of query is by executing a subquery
or creating an additional "from" clause:

```
Root<BooleanElement> from2 = criteriaQuery.from(BooleanElement.class);
Predicate joinPredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(from, from2);
....
```